# How to integrate Lambda, Alexa, and my code (Python - Tweepy)?

Tags: python, handler, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to tweet something by talking to Alexa. I want to put my code on AWS Lambda, and trigger the function by Alexa.

I already have a Python code that can tweet certain string successfully. And I also managed to create a zip file and deploy it on Lambda (code depends on the "tweepy" package). However, I could not get to trigger the function by Alexa, I understand that I need to use handlers and ASK-SDK (Alexa Service Kit), but I am kind of lost at this stage. Could anyone please give me an idea about how the handlers work and help me see the big picture?

Answer (score 0):

Alexa ASK_SDK Psuedo Code:
This is pseudo code of the new ASK_SDK, which is the predecessor to the ALEXA_SDK.
Also note I work in NodeJS but the structure is likely the same

- Outer Function with Call Back - Lambda Function Handler

  - CanHandle Function

    - Contains logic to determine if this handler is the right handler.  The HandlerInput variable contains the request data so you can check and see if the intent == "A specific intent" then return true.  Else return false.  Or you can go way more specific.  (Firing handlers by intent is pretty basic.  you can take it a step further and fire handlers based on Intent and State.
  - Handle Function

    - Which ever "canHandle" function returns true this is the code that will be run.  The handler has a few functions it can perform.  It can read the session attributes, change the session attributes based on the intent that was called, formulate a string response, read and write to a more persistant attribute store like dynamodb and create and fire an alexa response.

The handerInput contains everything you'll need.  I'd highly recommend running your test code in Pycharm with the debugger and then examining the handlerInput variable.

The response builder is also very important and is what allows you to add speech, follow up prompts, cards, elicit slot values etc.
`handler_input.response_builder`

Example to Examine
https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-helloworld-classes/blob/master/lambda/py/hello_world.py

```
class HelloWorldIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("HelloWorldIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        speak_output = "Hello Python World from Classes!"

        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )
```

Comment: Thanks Caleb, I managed to make Alexa tweet from my account. My next task is to make it tweet what I say, instead of a constant text message. Any hints on that?

Comment: @Gorkem for alexa this is an annoying question because it's actually very difficult to get a custom message from the user.  That said I'd recommend AMAZON.SearchQuery.  Your skill phrase will be something like "Tell twitter bot to tweet Hello world" where your invocation name is "Twitter Bot" your utterance is "tweet {Message}" and Message is a slot of type "Amazon.SearchQuery"

Comment: @gorkem if I had to give great advice it would be Google Home gives you the entire transcript of an interaction every interaction so you can run your own analysis on what was said.  this is also amazing because you can get custom user messages and googles nlp is great.  So... have you checked out google home/ api.ai?

Answer (score 0):

For your question about capturing user's input for tweeting, use AMAZON.SearchQuery slot type.  You may run into limitations about how much text can be collected and the quality of the capture but SearchQuery slot is the place to start.